# How to use Opentip with D3

Tags: d3.js, opentip

I'm trying to take advantage of the feature set from Opentip.js in a program that uses D3.js to map data.

I can't figure out how to tie a new Opentip object to the unnamed elements that comprise the map.

Here's a code extract that illustrates the approach I'm taking:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataset = [[4,2,'Bob'], [5,7,'Sally'], [2,2,'Marvin']];
var width = 38;
var height = 38;
var margin = 20;

function giveX(d) { return d[0] * width + margin }
function giveY(d) { return d[1] * height + margin }

var mapdiv = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", 680)
    .attr("width", 980)
    .style('border', '1px solid black')

var pips = mapdiv.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .style("fill", "red")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return giveX(d)})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return giveY(d)})
        .attr("r", width/2)
</script>
```

The constructor for the Opentip object simply needs me to supply an element identifier, but I'm not clear about how to refer to the dynamically created "circle" elements.

I've tried appending code to the selectAll() call but that doesn't work out.

Comment: I don't think open tip can target SVG elements. Also, it renders using canvas, which is also going to conflict with your SVG map. You might want to use [D3-tip](http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/) instead

Comment: Actually, the examples [Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/16363/mark]) provided work perfectly. I'm familiar with D3-tip, but specifically want to use features from Opentip. It turns out that there are TWO ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example using the `data-ot` attribute:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/opentip/2.4.6/downloads/opentip-native.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/opentip/2.4.6/css/opentip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 200)
        .attr('height', 200);
        
      svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(d3.range(10))
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return Math.random() * 200 } )
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return Math.random() * 200 } )
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style('fill', 'steelblue')
        .attr("data-ot", function(d,i){
          return "Circle " + i;
        });
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

And here's an example using the constructor:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/opentip/2.4.6/downloads/opentip-native.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/opentip/2.4.6/css/opentip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 200)
        .attr('height', 200);
        
      svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(d3.range(10))
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return Math.random() * 200 } )
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return Math.random() * 200 } )
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style('fill', 'steelblue')
        .each(function(d,i){
          new Opentip(this).setContent("Circle " + i);
        })
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```